# mutual_friend_count is sometimes null when running an FQL query

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am running this FQL query:

> SELECT uid,name,mutual_friend_count FROM user WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) ORDER BY mutual_friend_count DESC

I am getting back the list of my friends but for most of them (not all) I am getting null at the `mutual_friend_count` field.

This used to work fine until very recently (discovered it today when my app stopped working)
Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: We have the same issue starting today. So I can confirm it is not your fault.

Comment: @Szellszi Thank you for your confirmation

Comment: There's an open bug report at FB here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/242368225968716/ Probably it's fixed at FB speed, meaning NOT soon...

Comment: I too can confirm it, may be facebook broke something during f8.

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been fixed on May 8 https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/242368225968716/. The call for apps using 2.0 and above will now return only mutual friends count of friends using the app.